# Why does MSVC use system DLL's rather than toolkit DLL's?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have MSVC 141 / VS2017 and two Windows toolkits installed (10.0.17763.0 and 10.0.18362.0). However, do I get to really choose which ucrtbase.dll is being used? VS automatically uses my system DLL's despite there being several variants in the Microsoft SDKs / Windows Kits part of the file system. It also uses these system DLL's regardles of building my program with Windows SDK Version 10.0.17763.0 or 10.0.18362.0.

```
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\business\source\repos\YZ\x64\Release\AEC_Demo.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\business\source\repos\YZ\x64\Release\AEC_DLL.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
:
```

Here is the dll.intermediate.manifest (I also build a DLL that Demo.exe uses):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Here is Demo.exe's manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220003/discussion-on-question-by-julius-baer-why-does-msvc-use-system-dlls-rather-than).

Answer (score 3):

When you run on Win32; you have to load the Win32 dlls into your process or nothing works. Unlike certain other operating systems, on Windows, the syscalls are not the ABI surface, but rather the shared libraries (dlls) provided by Windows such as kernel32.dll, user32.dll, gdi32.dll, and advapi32.dll. kernelbase.dll and ntdll.dll are dependencies of kernel32.dll.

ucrtbase.dll is another OS component with similar rules, just not a mandatory component. If you use this component you link against the OS version of that compoment, and and a version from one OS won't work on another OS.

For these dlls, setting the SDK version lower changes the version you link against (by linking against older .lib files) but not the version you run against. Trying to use functions that aren't in the older version of Windows won't work unless you call them dynamically.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220004/discussion-on-answer-by-joshua-why-does-msvc-use-system-dlls-rather-than-toolki).

Comment: @Joshua, understanding that these DLL's are loaded is one thing. RbMm's comments are useful in pointing to the manifest. But I still feel like I have little control over what DLL's are loaded. What is the most fail safe/fool prove/overruling way to choose, so that I can control the DLL being used easily? How do I `prevent certain System DLL's being loaded explicitly`?

Comment: @JuliusBaer: You don't. The only way to run against another version of a system dll is to run on the version of Windows that uses that version of the system dll.

Answer (score 1):

You might be discovering a critical difference between Windows and Linux.

On Linux, the usual approach is that you compile software to run on your local machine, and just there. It's generally a miracle if that binary runs somewhere else. Therefore, you link your program against the system libraries. The flip side of this is that Linux crosscompiles are an utter nightmare.

Windows builds on the other hand are effectively always cross-compiles. You compile against a Windows SDK, not the system libraries on which happen to live on your particular build machine. Those SDK's in turn support a number of Windows versions, *up to* the indicated version, but usually also for older versions. The UCRT goes back to Windows 8.1 IIRC, even if you use the 10.0.18362.0 SDK.

Now if you then *test* your executable, you now use your PC as a runtime environment. It doesn't matter that the same PC has one or more Windows SDK installed. You can't expect end users to have SDK's installed, after all. It's Windows, the typical user is not an engineer. Therefore your executable uses the system DLL's. And if you need Visual C++ DLL's, you'll need to include the VC++ redistributable in your installer.

Comment: "if you need Visual C++ DLL's, you'll need to include the VC++ redistributable in your installer" That may be it, I actually think I just need them in my Release builds to fix a bug.

Comment: @JuliusBaer, as I mentioned in comment that got moved to chat, you can override "known DLLs" such as "ucrtbase.dll", for which the system normally uses a pre-mapped section object, either with ".local" redirection or, if the executable has a manifest (in which case .local redirection is ignored), with a dependent assembly.